# Java 8, Static methods vs Functions

Tags: java, static, functional-programming

In Java 8 I want to create something that returns an argument or creates an instance if the argument is null.

I could do this by creating a static method or a UnaryOperator. Are the following approaches technically the same or are there technical differences that I should be aware of with either approach:

**Static Method**

```
static Cat initOrReturn(Cat c) {
    if (c==null) {
        return new Cat();
    }
    return c;
}
```

**Function**

```
UnaryOperator<Cat> initOrReturn = c -> {
    if (c==null) {
        return new Cat();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Re, "...could be used in ... streams."  And would that help you to solve your problem?  Or would it help some other software developer with whom you are working to solve a problem?  You are asking developers for their opinions, but those opinions are going to depend on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: P.S., instead of "function," you might want to say "functional object."

Comment: Is `c -> c==null? new Cat(): c` really worth a discussion about different ways of reusability?

Comment: The question was really about the technical considerations of using a static method vs a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your code has syntax error, in the second block first line between `c` and `{` there should be a `->`.

The second one creates an anonynous object, the first one only creates a static method.
So they're not the same.

Also, static methods can be used in stream API.
If you have:

```
class A {
  static Object a(Object x) { return x; /* replace with your code */ }
}
```

You can:

```
xxxList().stream().map(A::a)
```

Creating a method is often considered dirty, because it's globally visible.
It's recommended to use lambda expressions without declaring a variable.

Comment: So it sounds like the only technical consideration when deciding which approach to take, is that the Function creates an additional object. If this is a concern, then go with the static method?

Otherwise, they both are easy to read, achieve the objective and can be used in streams.

Comment: Creating a method is often considered dirty, because it's global visible.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating pls. Don't both approaches allow visibility restriction by the addition of visibility modifiers e.g. private etc?

Comment: Even it's private, it's accessible to the whole class. While a lambda expression can be a local variable, you can restrict its scope inside a method, or a for/while/if/else/dowhile block.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If you find this helpful you can upvote/accept this answer ;)

Comment: I did, but sadly my current reputation level means the vote is not publicly visible :) but I have accepted it.

Comment: Anyway thanks. :) Actually this is not a bad question, but you may ask it on the [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about function as a "value" - something that can be stored to variable, and passed around.

This "value" can be used as e.g. method parameter to (during runtime) dynamically change part of method implementation.

Take a look at this basic example. Hope that can illustrate idea:

```
static Number functionsUsageExample(Integer someValue, UnaryOperator<Number> unaryOperator) {
    if (someValue == 1) {
        //do something
    }
    Number result = unaryOperator.apply(someValue); // dynamically apply supplied implementation
    // do something else
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UnaryOperator<Number> add = i -> i.doubleValue() + 20;
    UnaryOperator<Number> multiply = i -> i.intValue() * 3;

    var additionResult = functionsUsageExample(1, add);
    var multiplicationResult = functionsUsageExample(1, multiply);
    
    //additionResult value is:           21.0
    //multiplicationResult value is:     3
}
```

Function can be also used as a 'helper methods' stored inside method block. This way you will not corrupt class scope with method that is used only in one place.